# how to read line from console and store it into string in c++?

Tags: c++, linux

I have to read a whole line from the console and store it into a `std::string` and a `char` array,
e.g.

```
"Hi this is balaji"
```

Now I have to read the above string and store it into `string`. I tried it using the `getline()` function.

Comment: What's the problem? Didn't `getline()` work?

Comment: I recommend a good book, [any of these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string line;

    std::getline(std::cin, line);  // read a line from std::cin into line

    std::cout << "Your Line Was (" << line << ")\n";

    std::getline(std::cin, line);  // Waits for the user to hit enter before closing the program
}
```

Comment: i tried but the control does not stop at the in put, my code is as follow:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's something wrong with how you use cin.getline()?

```
  cin.getline (name,256);
```

[C++ refence for getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/)

Comment: Don't use that version of getline. What happens if the line is bigger than 256 characters or even worse what if the buffer is smaller than 256 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
string a;
cin >> a;

cout << a << endl;
```

Or something like that?

Comment: it reads some input from the user, but the OP specifically asked for help with reading a "whole line", and this doesn't.